# poll answer handler with pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I've sent a poll using this:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_poll(message.chat.id,'choose one',['a','b','c'])
```

but how could I get the answer back?

the documentation say's:

Handle poll answers @bot.poll_answer_handler() # <- passes a PollAnswer type object to your function.

but I didn't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access and print poll answers this way:

```py
@bot.poll_answer_handler()
def handle_poll_answer(pollAnswer):
    print(pollAnswer)
```

In python we can use the @ symbol along with the name of the decorator function and place it above the definition of the function to be decorated.

So here we put
`@bot.poll_answer_handler()` on top of our `handle_poll_answer` function for it to be registered as the bot's `poll_answer_handler`.

Note that it also says the handler will receive a `PollAnswer` type, so we put that as a parameter to our function as `pollAnswer`.

> passes a PollAnswer type object to your function

Comment: Hello friend! Idk how to use this code and I don’t want to create new answer. Could you please define how to get chosen variant from pool? If I merge two code examples my bot don’t get pollanswer. Maybe first function should be another?