# poll answer handler in telegrapm bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to get poll answer from user.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69961289/poll-answer-handler-with-pytelegrambotapi), but it doesn't work for me.

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, 'chose', ['a', 'b'])


@bot.poll_answer_handler(func=lambda call: True) #without lambda doesn't work too
def hadle_poll(call):
    print(call)
```

I don't know how to catch it. Please help

**EDIT**

I'm using `pytelegrambotapi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple.
In **anonimous** poll's you can't catch answers. So you should add one flag:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_poll(message.chat.id, 'chose', ['a', 'b'], is_anonymous = False)
```

Then your poll handler will work and catch answers.